# Assigning method to variable and problems with this

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
function A(){
    this.count = 0;
}
A.prototype.inc = function(){
    this.count++;
}

var a = new A();
a.inc();
var f = a.inc;
f();
```

The last line deosn't work as I expected, because `this` is an object of type `Window`. Is this just something, that you shouldn't do - assign methods to variables, in case they make use of `this`?

When I want to use a method as an argument, should I omit `fn(a.inc)`, which i would use for a regular function, and use insted the following?

```
fn(function(){
    a.inc();
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `call`? It lets you specify `this` when calling the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the famous "lost binding" of JavaScript.

you have to do:

```
f = a.inc.bind(a);
```

because if you say

```
f = a.inc;
f();
```

then when `f` is running, the `this` is not bound to `a`.  It is bound to the global object, which is `window`.

The rule is, if you say `a.fn()`, then inside of the function, `this` is bound to `a`, but if you just say `fn()` or `g()`, even when `g === a.fn`, then inside of the function, `this` is bound to the global object, which is `window`.

To bind `this` explicitly to `a` when the function is invoked, you have to use `a.inc.bind(a)`

If you don't want to use `bind` but want to use your own function, that's fine too.  You would do:

```
function fn() {
    a.inc();
}
```

or another form:

```
var fn = function() {
    a.inc();
};
```

this way, `fn` is a closure that captures the context, and is able to use `a`, which is in a scope in the scope chain.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript a "method" is not really tied to the object. It's just a function that's stored in a property. The binding of `this` happens when you call it with the dot notation, and therefore it doesn't work if you assign the method to a variable.

There is a handy built-in method called `bind` on functions that allows you to permanently bind `this` to a value. If you do this:

```
var f = a.inc.bind(a);
```

you will get the behavior you wanted.

Using the inline function also works, because it captures `a` and you still use the dot notation to call the method, which correctly binds `this` to your object.